# Why different diagnostics by clang on similar issue?

Tags: c++, diagnostics, type-narrowing

Here is my code:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 2.2};
}
```

As expected this does not compile because of the illegal narrowing conversion:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp
foo.cpp:5:30: error: type 'double' cannot be narrowed to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 2.2};
                             ^~~
```

Why does this compile then with only a warning?

```
#include <complex>

int main()
{
    std::complex<int> a = {1, 2.2};
}
```

Here is the warning:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp 
foo.cpp:5:31: warning: implicit conversion from 'double' to 'std::__1::complex<int>::value_type' (aka 'int') changes value from 2.2 to 2 [-Wliteral-conversion]
    std::complex<int> a = {1, 2.2};
                          ~   ^~~
1 warning generated.
```

I understand the notion of diagnostics and that the C++ compiler is only required to issue a diagnostic either in the form of error or warning.

But I want to be sure that I am not misunderstanding any concept here. Especially, I want to know if there is any C++ concept that I need to know why in the first case the `c++11-narrowing` diagnostic was issued but in the second case `literal-conversion` diagnostic was issued.

Comment: Unlike the vector example, there are no [`std::complex` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/complex) taking an initializer list. So there are no narrowing conversions. See e.g. [this list initialization reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two different things are happening, which as you can see result in different diagnostics:

- In the first case, you're using *copy-list-initialization* and finding a constructor of `std::vector` which takes an `std::initializer_lsit`.
- In the second case, you're using *copy-list-initialization* on a `LiteralType`, which results in *aggregate initialization*.

They both should prevent narrowing conversions, but it seems that clang implements the diagnostics differently.